# Java File Corrupted

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Yesterday, i've Closed Eclipse & then Turned Off The Computer, Now it's appear that a Crash has occured, when i started Eclipse again, Project List was empty So i've imported the Projects Again,

Problem : a Java Files is now corrupted, the file size seem correct, i can Open the File but the File is filed with "NUL" when i open it with a Text Editor & is empty when i open it in Eclipse,

I've tried to use the History Features of eclipse but there is No Any Backup in the .History Folder, only empty folders,

Is there any way to recover this Damaged .Java File ?

Thanks

Comment: if you use SVN, or other version controls, or ever back up your PC, you could look at restoring it from there. However, by your description, this doesnt seem likely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im trying a System Restore...

Comment: System Restore has Not Fixed this Problem :/ nevermind

Comment: I answered this [here][1] which WORKS everytime :)
Please have a look


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32440507/5309409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use SVN, or other version controls, or ever back up your PC, you could look at restoring it from there. However, by your description, this doesnt seem likely.

Noting from your comments you have tried a system restore.. System restore points and backing up your PC are two different things.

Right click on your file -> Properties.

The click "Previous Versions" along the top. 
It may say "There are no previous versions available", or may offer a restore choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've rewritten again this Java File based on an older backup version

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you had previously deployed the project you can get at the class file and de-compile the class back to code but that may still result in some loss. Also just try doing a search on your machine for that file name perhaps it was backed up by you at an earlier time that you forgot about.

Comment: Yes i have a Backup but from about 8 Month, i've made somes changes since this time, Thanks for your answer