# Gradle sync failed: Build file '...\build.gradle' should not contain a package statement

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My application was working perfectly fine, I dont know what happened all of a sudden the build.gradle throw an error stating Gradle sync failed, build file '...\build.gradle' should not contain a package statement, the thing is I checked my other apps as well and they had the same package com.example.myapplication;

here is my build.gradle(project:FaceRec);

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.E;
```

and here is the build.gradle with in the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary347')

    dependencies {
        api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    }

}
```

if any further clarification is needed please let me know.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks L2_Paver for the guide. I noticed that the build.gradle(project:FaceRec) is having contents that does not make sense, I dont know where and how it was there, so I changed the whole code and pasted an empty project's gradle and added some of the references, now with the replaced code as below the application started to work fine.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [Android Studio java file gets corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175409/android-studio-java-file-gets-corrupted/41651518)

Simply delete your caches should mostly solve your problem.

C:\Users\cc.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches

Comment: I have tried Invalidating Caches and Restart, also removed the content of caches, yet the problem persists. thanks.

Comment: try viewing your code using notepad via file explorer. if your code is correct try transferring the your project folder anywhere and open it again.

Comment: also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents