# XML content on android studio on my application is distorted

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

whe i open XML layout on android studio it appears distorted eg

�PNG

IHDR   0   0   W��   bKGD      �C�      pHYs    g��R    vpAg   0   0 ��W  �IDATh޵Yi�U���9��o�{^&I�B�A&  �� �( � "��`����b*H�Q�d�ZT�e�f
    !aJ�KHޔ7�{�V�9g��Q���vK�Z�Z��}�^U����}�>�vq<��8��cx%~�UO�|�T�o���=�V|���b0 @@��R���\U�A '�T��X�����<l���.^v�,���*�W�aN�u4-o���ylL�;�#?Q��w�bԳJ�`�L_nmz@OU����ҟ��7��G����������C�1�]��v��!WJU\wU���=]n
�!�*W���������s~�B2�J�uC&�룓z*�z���5�z�3Ou_��/�k�7�W�k��7�����b�:>}M'1�x8�Vi�Z

but when i open the same on notepad++ at appears to be OK, also when i run the application it runs just fine.

how can i correct this? i have tried invalidate cashes/restart but it doesn't work

Comment: That's common with android studio running on windows os

Comment: To fix this go to documents->delete 3 folders -> .android -> .androidstudio .->.gradle
after deleting restart your studio everything will be fixed

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175409/android-studio-java-file-gets-corrupted/41651518
Simply delete your caches should mostly solve your problem.

C:\Users\cc.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches

Comment: this worked thanks alot much appreciated